# Creating ppa for other ubuntu releases

Tags: apt, software-installation, ppa, release-management

I have ppa for the ubuntu 17.10 artful release. Now i want my ppa to work in ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 release so do i have to create seperate ppa for other releases or there is any way to install my software in all ubuntu release with single ppa .

Note- my software is compatible in ubuntu 16.04 and 16.10 release

Comment: Hi AMAN, just curious, but did you manage?

Answer (score 4):

#### Copying packages to other versions

Assuming you are on Launchpad:

1. Click from 'Personal package archives' on the ppa you want to edit.
2. Click subsequently on 'View package details' (right of 'Overview of published packages')

   ---

   [image]

---

3. On the upper righ, you will see 'Copy packages', click that one, and you will see check-boxes appear next to the packages.

   ---

   [image]

---

4. Click the one you want to copy over to other versions, then below the list of packages, choose the targeted 'Destination series' (Ubuntu version), and choose 'Copy existing binaries'.

   ---

   [image]

---

Then push the button <kbd>Copy packages</kbd>

That's it. Now the ppa is available on the Ubuntu version you copied it to (actually it might take a minute or 20).

#### N.B.

#### 1. Same version of software works on multiple versions

This only works if, as you indicated, the very same version works on different versions of Ubuntu. Else you need to rebuild a specific version.

If only *dependencies* versions differ, you can probably create a multi-version -version by including different versions in your control file with a `"|"` e.g.:

```
Depends: python3,
    python3-gi,
    gir1.2-budgie-1.0 | gir1.2-budgie-desktop-1.0,
```

#### 2. EOL

As @doug already mentioned in a comment, 16.10 is eol, and Launchpad does not allow copying packages to 16.10 anymore.

Comment: This will work fine if the copied  package will install & run in the targeted earlier release. If not then you'd need to do a rebuild which would use the targeted releases's libraries. Re: 16.10, it's eol so not sure if launchpad will allow any further builds..